# Add a list into a BinarySearchTree <Integer, List<Object>>

Tags: java

I'm new in Java and I want to add a list into a `BinarySearchTree` with an Integer as a Key and a List as value.
So I need every element of a list that I want to add and add to the BST.
I'm using BST because I need to sort it with the key.
In the class Group I have a method called `getNumber()` that return the number os elements in the that group and the key will be the number of elements of a Group.

Right now I have this and I don't know how to continue. 
`groups.iterator()` is just to iterate every group of a list.
orderedGroups is a `BinarySearchTree <Integer, List<Group>>()`.

EDIT:
I have this.

```
public Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<Group>>> listWarriors() throws NoGroupsException {
        if(!isThereGroup())
            throw new NoGroupsException();
        Iterator<Entry<String, Group>> it = groups.iterator();
        List<Group> listGroup = new DoublyLinkedList<Group>();
        int j = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            listGroup.add(j, it.next().getValue());
            j++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<j; i++) {
            List<Group> list = orderedGroups.find(listGroup.get(i).getNumber());
            if(list == null) {
                list = new DoublyLinkedList<Group>();
                list.addFirst(listGroup.get(i));
                orderedGroups.insert(-(listGroup.get(i).getNumber()), list);
            }
            else {
                if(list.equals(listGroup.get(i))) {
                    list.addFirst(listGroup.get(i));
                }
            } 
        }
        return orderedGroups.iterator();
    }
```

OrderedDictionary > orderedGroups = new BinarySearchTree>();

And a group is added by doing this.

```
public void addGroup(String idGrupo, String nome) throws GroupAlreadyExistsException {
        if(searchGroup(idGrupo))
            throw new GroupAlreadyExistsException();
        group = new GroupClass(idGrupo, nome);
        groups.insert(idGrupo.toLowerCase(), group);    
    }
```

I have all these in a Class called System.

Comment: Not sure why you are fussing with the Iterator.  If what you want to do a list to something, why not just iterate the list with  for (Type var : mylist) { myotherthing.add(var) }

Comment: @user1023110 Im just doing it to have the elements of groups's list

Comment: @xenteros I don't think so

Comment: @MauricePerry lol, I missed the tabs in the browser :(\

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you think you have to roll your own iterator in order to enumerate your list.    Not necessary.

I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do here, but maybe the below will help, which just demonstrates how to iterate a list.

```
void addListToGroup(List<Foo> myList, List<group> myGroups) {
   for (Foo foo : myList) {
      Object value=myList.someFunction();
      Group newGroup = new Group(value);
      myGroups.add(newGroup);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What can you tell me about my problem? @user1023110

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you're trying to do, and why you're not using LinkedList and TreeMap, but I see a few issues in your code:

1. your for loop makes i start at 1 whereas list indices start at 0,
2. building listGroup seems useless: you could directly build orderedGroups
3. orderedGroups is not modified in your code (orderedGroupsByC is though)

UPDATE:

What if you did this:

```
Iterator<Entry<String, Group>> it = groups.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Group group = it.next();
    List<Group> list = orderedGroups.find(group.getNumber());
    if (list == null) {
        list = new DoublyLinkedList<Group>();
        list.addFirst(group);
        orderedGroups.insert(group.getNumber(), list);
    } else {
        list.addFirst(group);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- I just correct it and it prints me 2 times when I have just a group in the list.
2- how can i do that?
3- in my code i have just orderedGroups. I add a "C" when pasting it here

Comment: I don't want that, I want to sort by the number of elements in a group because i can add users in a specific group. So this is wrong because it prints 2 times the same group because i just have a group.

Comment: how is orderedGroups built? can you update your question to reflect to changes you've just done?

Comment: i just did my changes and add more stuff about "groups" just for your understanding.

Comment: One more thing I don't get: why are you inserting at `-(listGroup.get(i).getNumber())`

Comment: Because i want to insert in orderedGroups each element in the listGroup with the key that is returned in getNumber

Comment: Oh!, and you're comparing a group with a list of groups: list.equals(listGroup.get(i))

Comment: @J.Doe yes, but why the minus sign?

Comment: Ok... What i want to do is to insert each group in list of groups in orderedGroups and sort it with the number of users in a group. So if I have two groups, groupA with 2 users and groupB with 1user when I print orderedGroups it will print groupA and then groupB.

Comment: the minus sign is to sort by descending order

Comment: Shouldn't orderedGroups be created here?

Comment: I don't know. Where do you suggest?

Comment: @J.Doe if you insert at -number, shouldn't you also search at -number?

Comment: @J.Doe I suggest to do so

Comment: I don't think thats the problem because I just put -number in search and it stays the same

Comment: Hard to make a diagnostic without the spec of BinarySearchTree